# Why is this makefile not working as expected?

Tags: makefile

```
func := sort
bar := a d b g q c
foo := $($(func) $(bar))
main:
    echo $(foo)
```

I expect the result `echo a b c d g q` apeared, but the result `echo` apeared.
When i change `foo := $(call $(func), $(bar))`, the expected answers apeared.
Whay this happend?

I search on google, question GPT, but don't get the answer.

Comment: Erm, because Make doesn't allow you to simply use a variable to contain the name of the function you want. That's why `$(call ...)` is necessary.